# Lex: Avoid a quoted expression

Tags: regex, quotes, lex

I'm trying to build a lex program which should avoid a quoted sequence of characters. Something like not(":="). I've written this so far but can't seem to be able to get the desired output:

```
/* Definitions */
assgn   ":="
symbol  [^{assgn}]

%%
.
":="    {printf("Found - %s\n",yytext);}
{symbol}  {printf("Error: Unmatched symbol \'%s\'\n", yytext);}
%
```

Input:

```
:= & | #
```

Output:

```
Found - :=
Error: Unmatched symbol ':' 
Error: Unmatched symbol '='
Error: Unmatched symbol '&'
Error: Unmatched symbol '|'
Error: Unmatched symbol '#'
```

Desired output:

```
Found - :=
Error: Unmatched symbol '&'
Error: Unmatched symbol '|'
Error: Unmatched symbol '#'
```

I want that the program avoids the ":=" as a whole but it still reads the single character ":". How do I correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"? The lexer must match *some* token at the current input location. It does not search for a token.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Pardon the ambiguity. What I mean is it should "match" the expression and eat it out since it has a '^' preceding it. Whenever ":=" appears, it should eat away the whole expression and not identify ":" and "=" as unmatched symbols.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "eat" in this context. If you want flex to recognize ":=" and do nothing when it sees it (i.e. continue scanning after it), then you only need to use an action which does nothing (or simply leave out the action.) If you mean something else, try explaining the sequwnce of desired matches with an example input. (Edit the question. The precision needed won't fit in a comment, and anyway that's not what comments are for.)

Comment: for example, for the input ":= * & |", only '*', '&' and '|' should be printed out as a result of negation of ":="

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. That file with that input produces the desired result. I would remove the line consisting only of a `.` and replace `{symbol}` with a `.` but for the sample input, it makes no difference.

Comment: Note: i had to remove the whitespace from the input. Perhaps you have some other rules you are not mentioning. But it is not easy to get lex to rescan a matched token without doing something explicit like calling yyless, which you don't mention doing.

Comment: I do have a long list of rules. But you get my problem. I have no experience of using  yyless and what result it would give me. The thing I want here is for lex to not read the same text for two or more different rule. Once it has read a rule, it should move ahead

Comment: And it will, unless you are doing something really odd. (Like invoking REJECT or calling yyless.)

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about using a REJECT or yyless to solve the above problem? Can you help?

Comment: Execode: My point is that if you are not using REJECT or yyless, you won't have that problem. Unless you have found some other odd way to force a rescan. Because flex does not rescan tokens once they have been matched.

Comment: I can assure you I am not. This is kind of a first experience that I'm having with "lex" (not flex) so I have tried to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Anyway, the complete (f)lex program in the answer produces precisely the desired output, and more or less matches the code in your question. Your code must differ in some significant way, since that is the only explanation for the apparent rescan. I have no idea what could cause that, but if you paste a complete compilable program which exhibits the invalid behaviour, I will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Also: please include the result of `lex --version` and (if you are on a linux system) `readlink -f $(which lex)` (which will tell us whether lex is symlinked to flex)

Answer (score 0):

The following little complete (f)lex program does precisely what is desired. flex will not rescan a matched token unless you ask it to (or, of course, there is some undefined behaviour in your code which corrupts flex's internal data structures.)

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
%}
%option nodefault noyywrap noinput nounput
%%

[[:space:]]+    /* Ignore spaces */
":="            {printf("Found - %s\n",yytext);}
.               {printf("Error: Unmatched symbol \'%s\'\n", yytext);}
```

With the above file stored in `only:=.l`, I do the following:

```
$ lex -o only:=.c only:=.l
$ gcc -o only:= -Wall only:=.c -lfl
$ ./only:=
:= & | #
Found - :=
Error: Unmatched symbol '&'
Error: Unmatched symbol '|'
Error: Unmatched symbol '#'
```

(`-lfl` adds a minimal definition of `main()`)

Comment: I already know that it is a character class and hence would match only a single character which is why this is happening. What I don't know is how to build an equivalent expression which matches strings and then I could negate that string. eg ":=" is a string which would match. What I want is to negate this match.

Comment: @execode, That doesn't make any sense, though. Your entire program is a string which doesn't match ":=". I don't think you want to match the entire input. So what is it that you actually want to match?

Comment: Well, simply put, the output I want is that everything should be printed except for ":=" for any text input file. Does it make sense?

Comment: I have a set of symbols that need to be recognized like ":=", ">=", "%%" etc. I need to print any unmatched symbol apart from this symbol jargon that I have. eg. ":", "=", "&" when they occur as separate entities. But the program identifies them as separate entities even when they are together. Also have this in the code: ":=" {yylval = NULL; yycolumn  = yycolumn + yyleng; return (ASSGNnum);}

Comment: Done. Edited the question.